# Remember last used user profile tab

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, activity-tab

When I click a username, I usually want to see their activity. Now for each username I click, I have to click 'Activity' again:

[image: Profile tab highlighted]

I want that to remember that I last visited the 'Activity' tab.

The profile page for other users already remembers which post sort order I have for their posts, so why not this tab as well?

Comment: Yes, it defaults to the "Profile" tab for other users and the "Activity" tab for oneself. Trying to get the Fanatic badge so I load my own profile just to see when I was "Last seen", and I have to do the extra click every time :/

Comment: I don't remember this _ever_ remembering the last-used tab.  Didn't it *always* open the "Profile" tab for other users and the "Activity" tab for oneself?

Comment: @Ryan AFAIK, it used to remember this on "other users" basis or even "per user" basis. Or maybe not. Then it's a feature request.

Comment: In my experience, the system never remembered which page in the profile was the last viewed and translated that to when you visit other users' profile pages. You can have direct links to each of the pages, so that might affect how you experienced this. When viewed by a non-moderator, the default page to be viewed is the user's actual "Profile" page. When viewed by a moderator, the default is the "Activity" page. Given the difference in default between regular users and moderators, it's something I notice on a regular basis (i.e. any time I go to a user profile on a non-Stack Overflow SE site).

Comment: @Makyen then I think it may be my muscle memory being thrown off by the redesign, i.e. I unconsciously always clicked "Activity" but now I have to actively search for it. Updated to feature request.

Comment: @CodeCaster I can certainly understand that. Personally, I use some CSS to put that tabbar back to where it was (i.e. at the top) and looking (mostly) like what it used to.

Comment: *"last used"* is not to be confused with the now [infamous "last seen" change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive/368289#368289).

Answer (score 8):

This user script seems to work as a redirect to the "Activity" tab for all user profiles, unless one has chosen to view a particular tab:

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Stack Redirect User Profiles
// @description  Go to the "Activity" page
// @version      0.1
//
// @namespace    scratte-fiddlings
// @author       Scratte (https://stackoverflow.com/users/12695027)
//
// @include      /^https://(?:meta\.)?askubuntu\.com/users//
// @include      /^https://(?:meta\.)?mathoverflow\.net/users//
// @include      /^https://(?:[^/]+\.)?stackoverflow\.com/users//
// @include      /^https://(?:meta\.)?superuser\.com/users//
// @include      /^https://(?:meta\.)?serverfault\.com/users//
// @include      /^https://stackapps\.com/users//
// @include      /^https://[^/]+\.stackexchange\.com/users//
// @exclude      *://api.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude      *://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude      *://elections.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude      *://openid.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude      *://blog.*.com/*
// @exclude      *://chat.*.com/*
// @exclude      *://contests.*.com/*
//
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    const host = document.location.host;
    const path = document.location.pathname;
    const search = document.location.search;
    if (!search) {
        const redirect = document.createElement("meta");
        redirect.setAttribute("http-equiv", "refresh");
        redirect.setAttribute("content", `0; URL=https://${host}/${path}?tab=topactivity`);
        document.querySelector("head")?.append(redirect);
    }
})();
```

Comment: I did have a few issues with being continuously redirected while making it, so.. be ready on the close tab "button", just in case :)

Comment: Nop, each and every bug solved with Script.

Comment: @Shree I agree. But life is too short to wait for 6-8..

Comment: Wouldn't it be "cleaner" to change all the anchors in the page? Something like `document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="/users/"]').forEach(anchor => { const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(anchor.search); if (!searchParams.has("tab")) { searchParams.append("tab", "topactivity"); } anchor.search = searchParams; });`. Seems like this would make less requests (but it would probably require some more work to avoid links to "https://anotherdomain/users/")

Comment: @Kaiido That's a good idea :) The directives would need a little adjustments too :)